# Why can't a tuple assignment be made with an add operator in Go?

Tags: go

According to [the Golang language syntax specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> [Assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) = [ExpressionList](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ExpressionList) [assign_op](https://golang.org/ref/spec#assign_op) [ExpressionList](https://golang.org/ref/spec#assign_op) .
>
> [assign_op](https://golang.org/ref/spec#assign_op) = [ [add_op](https://golang.org/ref/spec#add_op) | [mul_op](https://golang.org/ref/spec#mul_op) ] "=" .

furthermore:

> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued operation to a list of variables.

However, when trying to compile [the following code](https://play.golang.org/p/9xZC5LBmWgk):

```
package main

func addOne(a, b int) (int, int) {
    return a+1, b+1
}

func main() {
    var a, b int
    a, b += addOne(a, b)
}
```

the compiler complains with:

```
syntax error: unexpected +=, expecting := or = or comma
```

I'm aware temporary variables can work around this. E.g.

```
aTemp, bTemp := addOne(a, b)
a += aTemp
b += bTemp
```

However, it seems like something the language says it supports.

Is this a bug in the compiler?  Have I missed something in the language?

Comment: That would be some very confusing syntax. I'm glad it's not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is an assignment operation, not a simple assignment. The spec says explicitly:

> An *assignment operation* x op= y where *op* is a binary arithmetic operator is equivalent to x = x *op* (y) [...] In assignment operations, both the left- and right-hand expression lists must contain exactly one single-valued expression.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments